# Postgresql select max query takes long time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following structure in a table in my database. Below I list a part of the existing data.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DrQd6kb523wUZDaqhvkx6WBQxJ3wNT3n/view?usp=sharing

My data in text format

```
id    |       read_date        | value  | local_id | sensor_id 
---------+------------------------+--------+----------+-----------
 9732978 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |   25.2 |        1 |         1
 9732979 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |     26 |        1 |         8
 9732980 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |     65 |        1 |         2
 9732981 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |  150.5 |        1 |         4
 9732982 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |    6.2 |        1 |         5
 9732983 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |  926.9 |        1 |         7
 9732984 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |      1 |        1 |         3
 9732985 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |      0 |        1 |         3
 9732986 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |   31.2 |       10 |         1
 9732987 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |     32 |       10 |         8
 9732988 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |     65 |       10 |         2
 9732989 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |  150.5 |       10 |         4
 9732990 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |    7.5 |       10 |         5
 9732991 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 | 1132.9 |       10 |         7
 9732992 | 2020-11-19 14:14:30-03 |      1 |       10 |         3
```

I basically have sensors for temperature, humidity, wind speed and wind direction, and I store this information every 30s in the bank. are already have a certain amount of records. I'm having a problem with a select, I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, but I need to select the last value registered in the bank from the location and sensor I have this as select

```
select * 
from app_weatherdata 
where ((select max(id) 
       from app_weatherdata 
       where local_id=3 
         and sensor_id=1) =id);
```

But the return time for this consultation is too high, what is wrong with my consultation?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this index

```
create index on app_weatherdata(sensor_id, local_id, id desc);
```

this should be quite fast:

```
select *
from app_weatherdata 
where local_id = 3
and sensor_id = 1
order by id desc
limit 1
```

On a test table with 25 million rows and 100 distinct sensors and 100 distinct locations, I get this execution plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..4.60 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=5
  ->  Index Scan using app_weatherdata_sensor_id_local_id_id_idx on app_weatherdata  (cost=0.56..4627.36 rows=1147 width=32) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((sensor_id = 1) AND (local_id = 3))
        Buffers: shared hit=5
Planning Time: 0.085 ms
Execution Time: 0.032 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
select *
from app_weatherdata
where id = (select max(wd.id)
            from app_weatherdata wd
            where local_id = 3 and sensor_id = 1
           );
```

You want indexes on:

- `app_weatherdata(local_id, sensor_id, id)`
- `app_weatherdata(id)`

You have the second one, if `id` is declared as the primary key.

Comment: If you look at the image, you will see that there is a timestamp read_date field. What I was able to observe is that for those variables that have a very old record time, the query takes longer for those records that have more recent data.

Answer (score 0):

Getting max(id) then searching for the matching id requires 2 passes through the data. You should be able to reduce this to a single pass with

```
select  distinct on (wd.local_id, wd.sensor_id)  wd.*
  from app_weatherdata wd
 where wd.local_id = 1 
   and wd.sensor_id = 3 
 order by wd.local_id, wd.sensor_id, wd.id desc;
```

As @GordonLinoff pointed out as index on app_weatherdata(local_id, sensor_id, id) would be most useful.

NOTE: *It appears you have local_id and sensor_id reversed in you query vs. your data.*